# Waveform not showing while checking audio scrubbing

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

When I add an .mp3 sound file to the VSE and go to Playback and check Audio Scrubbing, I don't get the waveform. Why?

Comment: you probably don't wait long enough for the preview being loaded up? It might take some time...

Answer (score 8):

Turning on the waveform display is a separate setting in the 'View' menu:

[image]

If you have a long MP3, you may have to wait for the previews to generate (after turning 'Waveforms On'):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you have one or multiple Sound strips you can check *Draw Waveform* in the Strip Properties' *Sound* Panel (on the right, open VSE's Properties Panel pressing the <kbd>N</kbd> key).

When you want to set the behaviour for all Strips you can do so since the work on the [gooseberry branch](https://gooseberry.blender.org/gooseberry-tools-the-new-improved-sequencer/). They introduced this Feature there directly in the VSE's Menu Bar, but later implemented it in the Master Branch into the *View* menu with an own submenu *Waveform Drawing* where you can switch between two global options for turning Waveforms *On* or *Off* for all strips or let each strip determine on it's on property as described above whether or not to display its Waveform via *Use Strip Option*.
(You can script this if needed)

[image: Example of Waveform Drawing options]

Comment: Just as a note, while some people do like to highlight with backticks (``) that is generally reserved for highlighting code.